# how to delete an file after sending it to user as file response

Tags: python-3.x, django, flask

I'm trying to send a file to user as file response to the client. after user downloaded it successfully, I want to delete it from the server.
for example i downloaded a video file to server into a temp directory and giving it as response to user . then i wanna delete it ..
i used temp file to save video, but the directory is not deleted after using the file

but when i try to delete that file using add_post_render_callback() in django  and  @after_this_request  decorator in flask  and many more.
in every case i get error because either the file will be deleted before repose ( file not found - on file response )  or  the file is being used by file response so it cannot be used .  i also tried multi threading

```
res =request.POST\['res'\]
video_url=request.POST\['link'\]
\# Create a temporary directory within the Flask project root directory
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir= BASE_DIR / 'temp')

        # Fetch the YouTube video using pytube
        yt = YouTube(video_url)
        stream = yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4",resolution=res).first()
        video_path=stream.download(temp_dir)
        
        def callback():
            shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
        
        response = FileResponse(open(video_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename='video.mp4')
        response.add_post_render_callback(callback)
        return response
```